# PL/pgSQL function returns incorrect bitwise result

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a PL/pgSQL function `callbackfunc`. If I run it with bitwise result and unpack the result in my app, I got `65/0/65/65` (which is `1090535745`). If I return directly result of bitwise operation (`1094795585`) and unpack it, I got `65/65/65/65`. Why?

See sample below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION callbackfunc(value double precision[][][], pos integer[][], VARIADIC userargs text[])
    RETURNS double precision
    AS $$
DECLARE    
     var_result double precision;   
BEGIN
        var_result := (65 << 24 | 65 << 16 | 65 << 8 | 65 << 0);
        --var_result := 1094795585;   
    RETURN var_result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the operator's precedence. Bitwise-Or is higher than Shift. Your expression will be calculated as

```
var_result := (((((((65 << 24) | 65) << 16) | 65) << 8) | 65) << 0);
```

which gives 1090535745 (= 0x41004141). On the opposite

```
var_result := (65 << 24) | (65 << 16) | (65 << 8) | (65 << 0)
```

gives 1094795585 (= 0x41414141).